# How to debug a stored procedure in Toad?

Tags: oracle, debugging, stored-procedures, toad

I have Oracle 10g installed and there is a package which has a number of cursors and procedures, how do I debug one of these procedures or cursors. Can you please provide steps for that? 
I ran a Google search but did not find anything specifying how to debug a particular procedure from a package.

Comment: Good video with slightly different approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HCInbar5_o

Comment: Any hints on how to keep breakpoints between Toad restarts?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basic Steps to Debug a Procedure in Toad

1. Load your Procedure in Toad Editor.
2. Put debug point on the line where you want to debug.See the first screenshot.
3. Right click on the editor Execute->Execute PLSQL(Debugger).See the second screeshot.
4. A window opens up,you need to select the procedure from the left side and pass parameters for that procedure and then click Execute.See the third screenshot.
5. Now start your debugging check Debug-->Step Over...Add Watch etc.

*Reference:*[Toad Debugger](http://www.quest.com/toad/pdfs/how_to_use_toad_pl_sql_debugger.pdf)

[image: Debug]

[image: Execute In Debug]

[image: parameter]

Comment: And don't forget to give the necessary grant to your user.Once upon a time i lost 3 hours to this."grant  DEBUG CONNECT SESSION to your_user;"

Comment: Thanks Works well :D

Comment: it hangs for a minute....

Answer (score 1):

Open a PL/SQL object in the Editor.

Click  on the main toolbar or select Session | Toggle Compiling with Debug. This enables debugging.

Compile the object on the database.

Select one of the following options on the Execute toolbar to begin debugging:
Execute PL/SQL with debugger ()
Step over
Step into
Run to cursor